# SAXParser giving unexpected random results

Tags: java, android, saxparser

I am developing a RSS feed reader for Android, and for parsing XML files, I am using SAX APIs. The problem is that while parsing the data, some of the text is truncated in a random fashion in some randomly selected tags (I mean different instances of same tag). To me more clear, I have added a screenshot.

[image]

Here is my Handler class:

```
public class RssParseHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    private List<RssItem> rssItems;
    private RssItem currentItem;
    private boolean parsingTitle;
    private boolean parsingLink;
    //StringBuilder temp;

    public RssParseHandler() {
        rssItems = new ArrayList<RssItem>();        
        //temp = new StringBuilder();
    }

    public List<RssItem> getItems() {
        return rssItems;
    }

    @Override
        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        if ("item".equals(qName)) {
            currentItem = new RssItem();
        } else if ("title".equals(qName)) {
            parsingTitle = true;
        } else if ("link".equals(qName)) {
            parsingLink = true;
        }
    }    

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
        if ("item".equals(qName)) {
            rssItems.add(currentItem);
            currentItem = null;
        } else if ("title".equals(qName)) {
            //currentItem.setTitle(new String(temp));
            //temp = new StringBuilder();
            parsingTitle = false;
        } else if ("link".equals(qName)) {
            //currentItem.setLink(new String(temp));
            //temp = new StringBuilder();
            parsingLink = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
        if (parsingTitle) {
            if (currentItem != null)
            {
            //temp.append(ch, start, length);
             currentItem.setTitle(new String(ch, start, length));
            }
        } else if (parsingLink) {
            if (currentItem != null) {
                //temp.append(ch, start, length);
                currentElement.setLink(new String(ch, start, length));
                parsingLink = false;
             }
        }
    }
}
```

The methods `setTitle(String str)` and `setLink(String str)` are setter methods of class `RSSItem`.

I googled this problem and read somewhere to use `StringBuilder` instead. Hence I tried by using `StringBuilder`. ( I have commented the code when I used `StringBuilder`). But then I started receiving `NullPointerException`.

Any suggestions to get rid of this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the doc

> The Parser will call this method to report each chunk of character
>   data. SAX parsers may return all contiguous character data in a single
>   chunk, or they may split it into several chunks; however, all of the
>   characters in any single event must come from the same external entity
>   so that the Locator provides useful information.

So propably you are getting a partial chunk of data. A possible solution could be:

```
  if (currentItem != null) {
        //temp.append(ch, start, length);
        String tmpLink = currentElement.getLink();
        tmpLink += new String(ch, start, length);
        currentElement.setLink(tmpLink);

   }
```

of course `currentElement.getLink()` should return an empty `String` and not a `null` reference.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you assume `characters` method will handle all characters inside the element, which is not true.

You should save and concatenate new characters with previous characters if any.

Using `StringBuilder` is good for your cause. You just need to handle the NPE you've got.